# What is the use of nats in urls

Tags: url

As far as I was surfing the net, there were sites which had `?nats=` in their urls and at that I didnt care and said to myself that *Thats just some info to be sent* But from that time to now, Ive seen more sites using this in their urls.

```
http://example.com/sth.html?nats=NTE0MjogOjcz,0,0,0,27498

http://example.com/sth/2/?nats=MTU4Mo4yNS42LjQxLaAuOTE4LjAuMC4w
```

So my Question is: What is the use of this? Is it just some data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a tracking code, used to identify you or a referring web-site, though they don't always used the `nats=` prefix.

http://wiki.toomuchmedia.com/index.php/NATS should tell you all you need to know.

Comment: Do we need to have sth installed on our (PHP) server to achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to use it, or that you want to remove it from URLs to prevent tracking?

Comment: No. Using it  . -

Comment: My link above has a link panel for all the information you will need.